# Switch between spinner and listview based on screen orientation

Tags: java, android, listview, orientation, spinner

In my android application I have a spinner containing different calculators, and when a calculator is selected it shows up in a scrollview below. When the screen is set to horizontal, the layout changes so that the scrollview is to the right, and the spinner is to the left, and it all works the same way.

However, a listview would look better when the screen is in a horizontal position, but I can't seem to find a way to make the switch in the java code.

Can anyone help with this?

Here is the code for the initialize method, and I was wondering if there was a way to insert an if-statement where a spinner would be initialized if the screen was vertical, and a listview would be initialized if the screen was horizontal.

```
private void initialize() {

    valg_vertical = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sKalk);

    // Adds the custom look for the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.calculator));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(SpinnerItemLayout);
    valg_vertical.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Adds the custom look for the spinner

    lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lInSVKalk);
    valg_vertical.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possible solutions:

1. Create different layouts for `portrait` and `landscape` modes (they will be places under `layout` and `layout-land` folders respectively).
2. Create a container in your layout (`FrameLayout`, for example). And add corresponding view to it in runtime depending on orientation.

Anyway, since both orientations use different elements, in your code you should add the following `if` statement:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

} else {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!

I have made different views, but now I can't see how I can switch between them on runtime..

Comment: @jangerhard well, I believe the root cause is `NPE`? if so, you should find your views depending on orientation

Comment: I figured it out! I didn't change the ids for the different components, and now it works perfectly! Thanks again!